# select sum of one column with different condition

Tags: sql

I have two tables: revenue, departments.
The output is two columns are "total revenue for the marketing team in IL", and the other one for "total revenue for the marketing team in MN"

```
Select sum a. revenue, b. revenue
From Revenue
Left join dept ON revenue.account_id = dept.account_id
WHERE region= IL
    AND
    region= MN
Having dept=Marketing
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results. A non-working query and approximative explanation is not enough to get a helpful answer.

Comment: Probably should learn how to use `HAVING`.  In this case, it's not applicable.

Comment: `region` can't be equal to two things at the same time. The logic applies on a row by row basis.

Answer (score 0):

You basically need filtering in a `where` clause:

```
select sum(case when region = 'IL' then r.revenue end) as il_revenue,
       sum(case when region = 'MN' then r.revenue end) as mn_revenue
from Revenue r join
     dept d
     on r.account_id = d.account_id 
where region in ('IL', 'MN') and d.dept = 'Marketing';
```

Comment: I need two output columns one is "sum total revenue for the marketing team in IL", and the other one for "sum total revenue for the marketing team in MN"